# How do I prove that this integral is positive?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a monotonic decreasing positive function. While writing a proof, I came across the following integral:
$$\int_0^1f(x+n)-f(n+1)dx$$where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
I know that this integral is positive, but how do I write a rigorous proof of this being positive?

Comment: Isn't that negative? It is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\leq 1$ then $x+n\leq n+1$, hence $f(x+n)\geq f(n+1)$ since $f$ is decreasing. Therefore the integrand is non-negative, so $\int_0^1f(x+n)-f(n+1)\;dx\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\leq1$ then $x+n\leq1+n$ and $f$ is decreasing so $f(x+n)\geq f(1+n)$  or 
$f(x+n)-f(1+n)\geq 0$ thus $\int_0^1 f(x+n)-f(1+n)\geq 0$ or $\int_0^1 f(x+n)\geq\int_0^1f(1+n)$.